How to download and install the library for JZMQ AND JCZMQ
I'm trying to find the guidance to download and install the native library for JZMQ and JCZMQ, I had done implemented the code and ran successful using Jeromq dependency, Now stepping forward i want to know about the JZMQ AND JCZMQ. Help me to download and install the libraries.
I tried to get the solution for this but in ZeroMQ website they provided the code at download tab, but i dont know weather it is a library or some other.

While running the nmake command im getting this.
org\zeromq\ZDispatcher$1.class : no such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'echo >nul && "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\jar.exe" cf lib/zmq.jar org/zeromq/ZMQ.class org/zeromq/Utils.class
